# Unable to successfully change Postgresql data_directory and restart Postgres

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

My goal is to store my postgresql database data on an external ssd hard drive that I have plugged in to a machine running Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ARM x64. I am running into problems when changing the data directory in the postgresql.conf file and then restarting postgres.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Is the server running locally and accepting connections on 
Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am aware this error occurs when there is a problem with postgres configuration. I have tried setting permissions and ownership for user postgres on the /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main directory. No luck.

**Below are the steps I took:**

Create mount directory

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
```

Mount drive to directory

```
sudo mount -o defaults /dev/sda1 /mnt/data
```

Add directory to mounted drive where I want to store postgres data

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main
```

Change the data directory to /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
```

Restart postgresql service

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-initdb.html) to create a new data directory as user `postgres`, e.g.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/data/postgresql
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb -D /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main
sudo service postgresql stop
```

This also creates (unused) config files `postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_ident.conf` in `/mnt/data/postgresql/12/main`.

Now change the path to `data_directory` in `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`, start the service and test if the `data_directory` is set as expected:

```
sudo service postgresql start
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'show data_directory;'
```

This should output:

```
        data_directory        
------------------------------
 /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main
(1 row)
```

Comment: thank you for this. When I run the initdb command I am getting an error saying: fixing permissions on existing directory /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/mnt/data/postgresql/12/main": Operation not permitted. I made sure I used sudo but I am assuming since we switched to postgres with -u that the postgres user doesn't have permission to do this?

Comment: Run `sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/data/postgresql` before "initdb", the directory needs to belong to user `postgres`.

Comment: That got me through the initdb which looks like I have a bunch of new config files in the /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main folder. I had to do sudo su postgres to be able to CD into it. Can you explain what this did exactly?

Comment: You don't need to edit the config files in `/mnt/data/postgresql/12/main`, just change `data_directory` in `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf` and start the service. The default password is not set, use `sudo` to switch to the user. Please read [postgresql.org/docs/12/app-initdb.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-initdb.html).

Comment: got it! I am going to start fresh with all of this I forgot I accidentally moved all of the files from /etc/postgresql/12/main to /mnt/data/postgresql/12/main earlier when trying something. I will mark this as answer as soon as it works for me. Thank you so much! Is this the cleanest way to do what I am trying to do which is basically install postgres fresh on ubuntu server and then make it so the large data files are being stored on an external drive?

Comment: This is the clean way for a new database instance and I think it's the fastest solution to switch the data directory (edit one line in the original config, easy to revert).